# LaTeX -- vfill between two xltabular?

Tags: spacing, xltabular

I am trying to use a `\vfill` in between two separate `xtabular` tables, to put the second one all the way at the bottom of the page.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong, because it isn't working.  Can somebody please give me a pointer or a push?

**EDIT**  If I replace the `\vfill` with `\vspace{2in}` , I get the extra space declared.  However, replacing `\vfill` with `\vspace{\fill}` gives me no space.  I wonder if that's a clue.

**EDIT 2**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020 on Slackware) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-03>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
```

**EDIT 3**  I wrapped my bottom xltabular inside a `minipage` and that worked.

==========

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,margin=.5in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pbk}\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont
\tt
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X r r r r}
Game Name & Price & Listing & Commiss & Total \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\vfill

\begin{xltabular}{0.75\textwidth}{|X|}
\hline
GIFT CERTIFICATE TO CANTON GAMES FOR KURT RUNCO\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your tex distribution up to date? I do get the second table at the bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyo1u.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz   I honestly don't know, but highly doubt, that my distro is up to date.  My computer has turned into a frankenstein of packages and updates :(  But the fact that it works for you is clearly bad news for me.

Comment: If I replace the `\vfill` with `\vspace{2in}` , I get the extra space declared.  However, replacing `\vfill` with `\vspace{\fill}` gives me no space.  I wonder if that's a clue.

Comment: Just a wild idea: Does `\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}` work? (Note the triple `l`.)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen  No, the output looks the same.

Comment: I also noticed `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 20`  (that's the second `\end{xltabular}` .  I'm looking into that now...